# Apache Spark performance

Tags: java, caching, apache-spark

I have started studying Spark and currently I am running **WordCount** experiment (counts the number of appearances of each word in a text file)  with Spark. 
The file is placed in a network mounted shared filesystem. 
I have a cluster with **1 master and 5 executors** ( each has: Processor AMD Opteron 1.7 Ghz,  24 cores, 48GB RAM, 250GB storage).

I have left the default configurations of Spark for the moment (e.g. spark.executor.memory = 512m)

I have noticed that the first time I run the program I get a longer execution time, and this decreases at the second, third run.
For example for a 40GB file the execution times are:

1. First execution: 419.769396 s
2. Second execution:176.242206 s
3. Third execution: 134.411345 s
4. Fourth execution: 126.052158 s
5. Fifth execution:  126.287600 s

I am running it with:

```
> ./spark-submit --class com.spark.example.WordCount --master spark://master:7077 wordCountOriginal.jar /data/input40GB
```

The code of WordCount is exactly the same one from the examples provided by Spark.

I don´t understand why is there such a big difference between the first execution and the next ones. I was thinking caching is the answer, but from what I read Spark caches intermediate results inside the same execution, but here there are different executions.

Thanks is advance!

Comment: I think the difference might be more along the lines of pooling reusable data objects or keeping loaded classes in memory in the active instance. (Disclaimer: I've not worked with Spark).

Answer (score 0):

This is because Spark has a caching mechanism. After the first run, Spark will cache the result of the execution. You can read more about this at this [page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#caching). Good luck!

Comment: For a deeper dive - Under the hood, this is due to spark not calling fsync on the shuffle files so it will be written to the OS buffer cache

Comment: Thank you! Then, if I evaluate the performance, is it more accurate to take an average of a couple of execution times or only the first execution time?

Comment: @JustinPihony those are independent runs. There should not be any "memory" of previous runs in the Spark system. To me it looks like pure OS caching of 'hot' files.

Comment: @RoxanaRoman  as you can see from your experiment, first execution gives you more performance gain. So one execution enough.

Comment: @RoxanaRoman BTW, I don't believe this answer is correct. Those results  have nothing to do with caching in Spark. Spark caching is scoped  by the lifetime of the spark context and here with spark-submit, a new context will be created every time.

Comment: No, spark cache data in tmp directory, so data will be cached untill spark server is running, after spark restart, data will be deleted.

Comment: @JamesSchermann The files will be there, but Spark doesn't have enough information to associate them with the job. Besides, data has to be explicitly cached in Spark, which the word count example does not do.

Answer (score 0):

In order to eliminate these differences in execution time, after each execution I stopped the master and the nodes and cleared manually the OS cache. After more investigations, I think Spark deals with memory caching and dropping from cache only while the server is running  and it uses the LRU (Least recently used) policy for dropping data from cache. Without the manual clear of the cache, I was still seeing the decreasing execution time pattern.

Comment: Correct. Spark caching is not the culprit here. Firstly, you have to explicitly specify data should be cached, which the word count example doesn't do. Second, cache lifetime is tied to the lifetime of the Spark context. A new Spark context is created with each submitted job.